# Mostrar botão somente quando a barra de rolagem descer, usando vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Olá. Estou criando um botão "vá para o topo da página", usando vuetify. 
Já consigo fazer ele ir ao topo com o seguinte código:

```
@click="$vuetify.goTo(0,0)
```

Mas agora eu gostaria que ele somente aparecesse se eu rolar um pouco a página para baixo.

Tentei isso:

```
data() {
   topo: 0
}

methods: {
 sumir(){
   this.topo = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
 }
}
```

e depois fiz no botao:

```
:v-show ="topo > 100" ou  v-show ="topo > 100"
```

ambos sem sucesso. 
Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi com o seguinte código:

```
<template>

    <v-btn v-if="irParaTopo >= 200" color="info" dark fixed bottom right fab small
           @click="$vuetify.goTo(0,0)">
        <v-icon>expand_less</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        name: "IrParaOTopo",

        data() {
            return {

                irParaTopo: 0,
            }
        },

        mounted() {

            window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                var scrollAtual = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                this.irParaTopo = scrollAtual;
            });

        },
    }

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```